# NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init> exception while using Froyo version of Google Play Services

Tags: android, proguard, google-play-services, android-2.2-froyo

users of my app running Android 2.2 run into application crashes. The following stacktrace is shown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.IOException.<init>
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ii.e(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ii.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hf.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hf.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.cy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.eg.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ej.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

I have switched to the right version of Google Play Services to try to solve this issue (3.2.65, the one that still has Froyo support):

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
   ...
}
```

But this doesn't solve the issue: the application crashes are still happening on Froyo devices. I'm looking for a solution (could this be a proguard issue?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered the cause of my problem: I was including the right version of Google Play Services (3.2.65, still contains Froyo support) in the main app, but was including a library project (AAR) which was depending on a newer version of the same library (4.x).
After updating the library project to 3.2.65 some code in the library project was not compiling anymore (AdView usages). After solving the compilation errors, rebuilding the AAR and updating the main app to include this new version of the AAR the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new Google Play Services with froyo (revision 12).